# Spark : Understanding Dynamic Allocation

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have launched a spark job with the following configuration :

```
--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=19 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=0
```

It works well and finished in success, but after checking spark history ui, this is what i saw :

[image]

My questions are (Im concerned by understanding more than solutions) :

Why spark request the last executor if it has no task to do ? 
How can i optimise cluster resource requested by my job in the dynamic allocation mode ?

Im using Spark 2.3.0 on Yarn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of the allocation policy :

> Additionally, the number of executors requested in each round
> increases exponentially from the previous round.

[reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#request-policy)

Answer (score 1):

You need to respect the 2 requierements for using spark dynamic allocation:

- **spark.dynamicAllocation.enable**
- **spark.shuffle.service.enabled** => The purpose of the external shuffle service is to allow executors to be removed without deleting shuffle files.

The resources are adjusted dynamically based on the workload.  The app will give resources back if you are no longer using it.

I am not sure that there is an order, it will just request executors in round and exponentially, i.e: an application will add 1 executor in the first round, and then 2, 4 8 and so on...

[Configuring external shuffle service](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#configuring-the-external-shuffle-service)

Comment: You need to respect the 2 req => Its already configured and It works fine, but want to understand the behaviour. Thx

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what Spark did there without knowing the content of the job you submitted. Unfortunately the configuration string you provided does not say much about what Spark will actually perform upon job submission.

You will likely get a better understanding of what happened during a task by looking at the 'SQL' part of the history UI (right side of the top bar) as well as at the stdout logs.

Generally one of the better places to read about how Spark works is the official page: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

Happy sparking ;)